# How to delete symbols from a string in erlang

Tags: erlang, computer-science

I need to ignore/delete all the symbols in a string (read from a file, but that doesnt matter). How do i do it? This is what i have so far

```
Words = string:to_lower(loadFile(FileToLoad)),
TokenList1 = (string:tokens(Words," \r\n,.-")),
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use list comprehension:

```
S = "@1a#2b*c3d%+".
WithoutSymbols = [X || X <- S, Y <- lists:seq($a,$z), X =:= Y].
```

`WithoutSymbols` becomes `abcd`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `re` module's [replace/4](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#replace-4) function, where you replace all non-alphabet characters with empty string. You can change the second argument there to any whatever you don't what to keep in your final string.

```
S = "@1a#2b*c3d%+".
re:replace(S, "[^a-zA-Z]", "", [global, {return, list}]).
% Returns "abcd"
```

Pay attention to the options at the end as well, these options return a list in the end (can return binary if needed), and apply the replace globally not just on the first occurrence.